# How do I access a method that's in another method that's in a class in ECMA6Script?

Tags: ecmascript-6

How do I declare the method getYellowCycle() so that the variable game can access it? getYellowCycle is a method that's in another method called newGame(), that's in a class called model.game.

Here is where the method should be called.

```
let game = model.Game.newGame();
expect(game.getYellowCycle().getX()).to.equal(50);
```

Here is the class model.game

```
model.Game = class {

    newGame() {

    }
};
```

getYellowCycle() should go in newGame()

Comment: Maybe create a new constructor with the `getYellowCycle` method and make `newGame` return a new instance of that constructor? Or just return a plain object with the `getYellowCycle` method?

Comment: It looks like `newGame` should be a `static` method

Comment: Yeah both of you were correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
const model = {};
model.Game = class {

    newGame() {
        return {
            getYellowCycle() {
                return {
                    getX() {
                        console.log("In getX");
                        return 50;
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
};

const game = (new model.Game()).newGame();
console.log(game.getYellowCycle().getX());
```